# Woocommerce, new order email notification - products table empty?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Suddenly new order email notifications that my Woocommerce sends stopped displaying product items.

Thead content (product/price/quantity) is displayed but table content is empty. The email template is intact - for some reason product items are not loaded.

My WP core, Woocommerce and all of the plugins are up to date. I tried with PHP 5.4 and 7.1 and the problem persists in both cases.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you tried to disable plugins to prevent a plugin conflict?

Comment: Yes, I did that in addition as well. I disabled ALL of the plugins except Woocommerce. Including SMTP plugin. The problem is still there. This is really mind-boggling.

Comment: maybe the email template is override in your theme?

Comment: Nope, I'm using Twenty Sixteen Child Theme - it uses default theme's email templates. In fact, I even tried to copy the email templates to my childtheme - the problem is there in both cases.

Comment: Everything works fine with parent theme active! It must be related to my functions.php changes of the childtheme somehow. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using "woocommerce_new_order" hook in my functions.php file, that was causing the issue.

The solution was to replace it with another hook -> "woocommerce_checkout_order_processed"

Comment: Well, it solved my problem. I removed the "woocommerce_new_order" hook. :)

Comment: I just updated my answer to make more sense for someone having the same issue. :)